# Assist in Cleaning a MySQL Join Query to Find Changes Between Rows

Tags: mysql, join, otrs

Table size ~500,000 rows, 137MB, Query Time 1.591 sec

I am a junior programmer testing my mettle on our MySQL based OTRS ticket database. I'm looking for instances in which a ticket moves between queues. The indicator for a move exists on the same row as the new queue, and I have setup a query that attempts to return the previous value of the same column in the same ticket id.

Example of a Ticket in the Table:

```
id    history_type_id    ticket_id    queue_id            create_time
377                 1           30           2    2012-09-14 11:06:02
378                21           30           2    2012-09-14 11:06:02
379                12           30           2    2012-09-14 11:06:02
380                 4           30           2    2012-09-14 11:06:02
381                16           30           8    2012-09-14 11:08:29
383                16           30           2    2012-09-14 11:09:54
384                17           30           2    2012-09-14 11:11:28
                          ***  Stuff Happens  ***
396                27           30           2    2012-09-14 11:22:06
397                18           30           2    2012-09-14 11:22:06
```

The rows in question are **380**, **381**, and **383**. The **history_type_id** value for a move is **16**, and the row above **381** has the previous **queue_id** of the ticket. What I was able to build is a query that checks the previous **id** value before any **id** value with the **history_type_id** of **16** and that shares the same **ticket_id** and return the **queue_id** of that row (or so I assume. 100% self taught to this point). As you can assume, **id** and **create_time** are not limited per ticket, and cannot be used reliably to sort.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT OldQ.id,
       OldQ.queue_id AS OldOne,
       OldQ.create_time AS FirstQ,
       NewQ.id,
       NewQ.queue_id AS NewOne,
       NewQ.create_time AS LastQ,
       OldQ.ticket_id 
FROM ticket_history AS OldQ
    JOIN ticket_history AS NewQ
        ON OldQ.id < NewQ.id 
        AND OldQ.ticket_id = NewQ.ticket_id
WHERE NewQ.history_type_id = '16'
ORDER BY NewQ.ticket_id,
         NewQ.id,
         OldQ.id
```

This "works" but in an ugly and likely unacceptable way, it looks for every value of **OldQ.id** per **ticket_id** rather than just the one before **NewQ.id**, and that is where I hit the roadblock.  I have usable data, but it is far more than I need. For example, here is the output for the above ticket:

```
 id  OldOne               FirstQ   id  NewOne                 LastQ   ticket_id
377       2  2012-09-14 11:06:02  381       8   2012-09-14 11:08:29          30
378       2  2012-09-14 11:06:02  381       8   2012-09-14 11:08:29          30
379       2  2012-09-14 11:06:02  381       8   2012-09-14 11:08:29          30
380       2  2012-09-14 11:06:02  381       8   2012-09-14 11:08:29          30
377       2  2012-09-14 11:06:02  383       2   2012-09-14 11:09:54          30
378       2  2012-09-14 11:06:02  383       2   2012-09-14 11:09:54          30
379       2  2012-09-14 11:06:02  383       2   2012-09-14 11:09:54          30
380       2  2012-09-14 11:06:02  383       2   2012-09-14 11:09:54          30
381       8  2012-09-14 11:08:29  383       2   2012-09-14 11:09:54          30
```

Where what I'm attempting to drive to would be a return such as this:

```
 id  OldOne               FirstQ   id  NewOne                 LastQ   ticket_id
380       2  2012-09-14 11:06:02  381       8   2012-09-14 11:08:29          30
381       8  2012-09-14 11:08:29  383       2   2012-09-14 11:09:54          30
```

Been puzzling this one for hours today, I was so pleased when they query actually ran, but if these numbers can come alive, I will be ecstatic

Answer (score 0):

Sytharin, I haven't been able to test this yet, but a solution that I believe would work for you is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    OldQ.id,
    OldQ.queue_id AS OldOne,
    OldQ.create_time AS FirstQ,
    NewQ.id,
    NewQ.queue_id AS NewOne,
    NewQ.create_time AS LastQ,
    OldQ.ticket_id 
FROM ticket_history AS OldQ
JOIN ticket_history AS NewQ
    ON NewQ.id - 1 = OldQ.id
    AND OldQ.ticket_id = NewQ.ticket_id
WHERE 
    NewQ.history_type_id = '16'
ORDER BY 
    NewQ.ticket_id,
    NewQ.id,
    OldQ.id
```

Upon modifying the join statement to only look at the OldQ.id directly behind the NewQ.id, it should limit the results to the single row directly preceding the NewQ.id. Again, untested, but a small change in your query to see if it works.

Comment: Just noticed how old that was...a bit late to the party. Oops!